# Internet Explorer Enable Automatic Crash Recovery

Tags: internet-explorer-8

In IE8 there is the option: Enable Automatic Crash Recovery

I want to disable it using the registry but cannot find the setting for it.

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Why don't you disable it by clearing the `Enable automatic crash recovery` check box? It's in `Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Browsing`.

Comment: Yeah I know that is there but I need to do it via script (to automate the setup of machines)

Answer (score 2):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery]
"AutoRecover"=dword:00000002
```

- A value of `00000002` = disable
- A value of `00000000` = enable

Answer (score -1):

It can be done in the registry or via group policy. See [How to Turn Off and Disable Reopen Last Browsing Session in IE8](http://wiki.imacros.net/IE_Nags#How_to_Turn_Off_and_Disable_Reopen_Last_Browsing_Session_in_IE8)  for the two different methods.

Comment: That doesn't give the right value name for this setting...